# How can I do that html list?

Tags: html, list

I need to do a html list of elements like this pic:

[image: list]

I think its an external div that englobes li or option elements. It's possible?
Its for a form therefore I need to submit its value by post.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm a little confused... What exactly about this picture do you want to accomplish?

Comment: Provide a fiddle of code done by you.

Comment: What type of element?

Comment: You can achieve this list by creating an `<ul>` (see @mario595's answer), creating a `div` and filling them seperately or even a `table` by styling the `<tr>`

Comment: Looks like a `<select multiple>` rather than a list to me, especially when the OP mentioned a submit.

Comment: Need something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/CVTEQ/ BUT I need to get the value of the p that I click to send it to php by post.

Comment: <select multiple> THAT'S what I'm looking for!! Thanks!

Comment: I'll put it in an an answer for you then, give me a minute...

Comment: @Angel You need to be more specific next time. You never asked that you want to select multiple elements and your jsfiddle does not have any submit button, altough you mentioned it into your question.

Comment: Sorry. I was not sure how to ask this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow on from my comment...

```
<form>
  <select multiple>
    <option value="Element 1">Element 1</option>
    <option value="Element 2">Element 2</option>
    <option value="Element 3">Element 3</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U9Cdw/) helps you.

```
    <div class='wrapper'>
      <ul>
          <li>element 1</li> 
          <li>element 2</li>
          <li>element 3</li>
          <li>element 4</li>
          <li>element 5</li>
          <li>element 6</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And the Css

```
.wrapper{
    height : 100px;
    overflow : auto;
    width : 250px;
}
li{
    border : 1px black solid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do it from what i see here there are divs with `style="width:100%;float:left;"` and thats it

Answer (score 0):

It can be too many different ways to do it (`div`, `li` inside a `div`, `table`...). My suggestion, use `li` elements into a `div`. I prefer that, because you can change your `div` width and height, use overflow, etc. and your list will be more personal.

Example:

```
<div id="list-content">
    <ul>
        <li><span>Element 1</span></li>
        <li><span>Element 2</span></li>
        <li><span>Element 3</span></li>
        <li><span>Element 4</span></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And your CSS has to be something like this:

```
div#list-content {
    width: 200px;
    height: 500px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

li {
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 2px 0;
}
```